# Form data are updating in the database instead of INSERTING

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want store the form data into database but when I press the submit button, the rows in the database is updating instead INSERTING

from home page I am clicking the link called. **fetch_faculty_subject** which will retrieve some data from database and shows output as like dropdown list(in HTML ). again from *form* I am adding some data to the form and storing to the table called **Mapped_faculty_n_subjects**

this is my views.py

```
def fetch_faculty_subject(request):
    faculties= facultyhours.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    subjects= subject_code.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    classname= class_number.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    context1 = {
         'faculties': faculties,
         'subjects': subjects,
         'classes': classname
     }
    return render(request, 'createtimetable_for_class/selecting_subjects_n_teachers.html', context1)


def store_the_faculty_subject(request):
    userr = request.user.id
    selected_class_name=request.POST["classname"]
    selected_faculty_name=request.POST["facultyname"]
    selected_subject_name=request.POST["subjectname"]
    selected_total_hours_per_week=request.POST["totalhours"]
    faculty_n_subject_db=Mapped_faculty_n_subjects(selected_class_name=selected_class_name,selected_faculty_name=selected_faculty_name,selected_subject_name=selected_subject_name,selected_total_hours_per_week=selected_total_hours_per_week,user_id=userr)
    faculty_n_subject_db.save()
    # return redirect('/fetch_faculty_subject/')

    faculties= facultyhours.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    subjects= subject_code.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    classname= class_number.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    context1 = {
         'faculties': faculties,
         'subjects': subjects,
         'classes': classname
     }
    # return redirect(request,'createtimetable_for_class/selecting_subjects_n_teachers.html',context1)
    return render(request, 'createtimetable_for_class/selecting_subjects_n_teachers.html',context1)
```

this is my models.py

```
class Mapped_faculty_n_subjects(models.Model):
    selected_class_name=models.CharField(max_length=250,primary_key=True)
    selected_faculty_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    selected_subject_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    selected_total_hours_per_week=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

this is my html form

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>Select Faculty and Subject</h2>
                    <form method="post" action="/store_the_faculty_subject/">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                            <label>Select The Class</label><br>
                            <select name="classname">
                                 {% for classes in classes %}
                                <option>{{ classes.class_name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select><br><br>
                            <label>Select The Faculty</label><br>
                            <select name="facultyname">
                                 {% for faculty in faculties %}
                                <option>{{ faculty.faculty_name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select><br><br>
                            <label>Select The Subject</label><br>
                            <select name="subjectname">
                                {% for subjects in subjects %}
                                <option>{{ subjects.subject_name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select><br><br>
                            <label>Total hours per week</label><br>
                            <input type="number" max="34" name="totalhours" required class="textinput textInput form-control"><br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">NEXT</a>

                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is `selected_class_name` repeated in the post request ? Because a primary key should be unique and you are repeating it so it updates the existing, but maybe trying `<Model Name>.objects.create()`